# Unable to run docker container using python uwsgi

Tags: docker, uwsgi

I'm building a small Python(flask) app.

The Image is built successfully but Container is not running. When I run  `docker ps`, no running Container is found. Also docker logs shows `uwsgi not found`

identidock.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_docker():
    return 'Hellow docker!\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN pip install Flask==0.10.1
RUN pip install uWSGI==2.0.17
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app

CMD ["uwsgi", "--http", "0.0.0.0:9090". "--wsgi-file", 
"/app/identidock.py", "--callable", "app", "--stats", "0.0.0.0:9191"]
```

Commands ran:

```
sudo docker build -t identidock .   <<< no problem
sudo docker run -d -p 9090:9090 -p 9191:9191 identidock << no problem
sudo docker ps     << empty   
sudo docker logs <container ID>  > >>/bin/sh: 1: [uwsgi,: not found
```

Comment: Try adding the full path to `uwsgi` in your CMD line

Comment: code formatting and rephrased question

Comment: updated title, tags, and code formatting

Answer (score 2):

if you are building the docker image with this line `CMD ["uwsgi", "--http", "0.0.0.0:9090". "--wsgi-file", "/app/identidock.py", "--callable", "app", "--stats", "0.0.0.0:9191"]`, you have a dot after `"0.0.0.0:9090"` that you need to change by a `,`.

Docker file should be:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN pip install Flask==0.10.1
RUN pip install uWSGI==2.0.17
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app

CMD ["uwsgi", "--http", "0.0.0.0:9090", "--wsgi-file", "/app/identidock.py", "--callable", "app", "--stats", "0.0.0.0:9191"]
```

This should work...

Comment: You're welcome. if it works, could you mark the answer as correct?